# Html button doesn't fire and doesn't call server side

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

Html button doesn't fire and doesn't call server side and not save in data base
so what can i do

```
<div class="container-contact2">
    <div class="wrap-contact2">
        <form class="contact2-form validate-form">
            <span class="contact2-form-title">
                Patient Info
            </span>

            <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
                <asp:TextBox ID="fname" CssClass="input2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="First NAME"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="input2" ID="lname" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="Last NAME"></span>
            </div>
             <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
                 <asp:TextBox CssClass="input2" ID="Address" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="Address"></span>
            </div>
             <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="city" CssClass="input2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="City"></span>
            </div>
            <label class="custom-sel ">
              <select id="gender" runat="server" name='options'>
                <option  >Male </option>
                <option  >Female</option>

              </select>
            </label>
            <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                <label class="label" for="dateofbirth">Date Of Birth</label>
                <input class="input" runat="server" type="date" name="dateofbirth" id="birth">
                <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder=""></span>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
                <input class="input2" id="ssec" runat="server" type="text" name="name">
                <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="Social Security"></span>
            </div>
            <label class="custom-sel ">
              <select id="inppSel" runat="server" name='options'>

              </select>
                <input runat="server" type="hidden" id="inpTxt"/>
            </label>
            <div class="container-contact2-form-btn">
                <div class="wrap-contact2-form-btn">
                    <div class="contact2-form-bgbtn"></div>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="saveChanges" runat="server" Text="Button" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Code:

```
DataBaseConnection db = new DataBaseConnection();
db.disconnect();
string sql1 = "insert into TBL_Persons values( @First_Name,@Last_Name,@Address,@City)";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, db.connect());
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name",fname.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", lname.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city.Text);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
string sql2 = "Insert into TBL_Patients values(@Gender,@Date_OF_Birth, @Social_Security,@Person_ID, @Case_ID)";
db.disconnect();
string sql3 = "select max(Person_ID) from TBL_Persons ";
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql3, db.connect());
int max = (int)(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
db.disconnect();
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sql2, db.connect());
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender.Items[gender.SelectedIndex].Text);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_OF_Birth", birth.Value);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Social_Security", ssec.Value);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Person_ID", max);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Case_ID", inpTxt.Value);
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
Label1.Text = "Patient Saved";
```

Comment: My webforms knowledge is fading fast, but shouldn't the `<form>` tag also be `runat="server"`?

Comment: [This is the best reference I can find](http://w3schools.sinsixx.com/aspnet/control_htmlform.asp.htm) that says `runat=server` is required.

Comment: And you cannot use a form in a form, should there be a form with runat=server at the very top of the page, which is the case with winforms.

Answer (score 0):

`

```js
function saveChanges()
{
PageMethods.save();
}
```

```html
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="saveChanges(); " runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

```
    [WebMethod]                               
    public static void save()
    {
      //c# code here

    }
```